# How to pass objects list to Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

> It is billing form when i want to **add purchase item name, qty and
>   price  and add this multiple times accordingly total amount will calculate**
>   final when click on submit button to submit all this included item
>   with other parameter like bill no,bill date etc.

controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ProjectPurchasesMutiple(ProjectPurchases ym)
 {
    return View();
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to define two different forms

1. Receipt details form: having receipt details i.e. Purchased Item
   name, quantity & Price
2. Bill details form i.e. Bill number, date etc.

Define two global variables

1. TotalResults: to calculate total results
2. Array of Objects to tackle the list of receipt details. **(var receiptsList = [])**

Each time "add stock" event is fired serialize and add resulting object of receipt details to objects array 
(you can use **.push()** jQuery method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) as well as sum up the total amount. (You can do it by calling **.serialize()** jQuery method details at: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

On Submission Serialize billing details form and Add both previously defined Receipts list array and variable to this new serialized object and send it to controller.

`var billingDetails = $("billingDetailsForm_Id").serialize()
billingDetails["recieptsListName"] = recieptsList`

Comment: thank you for reply any coding demo which understood me better

Comment: Share your code so that I can guide you about appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a session variable when load form with empty array its value
2. When click on add stock add the values to this session variable
3. List item from the session variable to display in the form
4. When trigger submit add items from this session variable